# getting "~lock" in file info fullname

Tags: vb.net

I am using fileinfo class in vb to get the the fullname of a file name  to insert into a listbox.

For example

```
Dim fs_infos() As FileInfo = dir_info.GetFiles("*.txt")
For Each fs_info As FileInfo In fs_infos
    listbox1.items.add(fs_info.FullName)
Next
```

and im getting

```
A:\.~lock.4142_062017.TXT#
```

instead of `A:\4142_062017.TXT`

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: How you populated fs_infos, if you have proper FileInfo object, it should show clear FullName.

Comment: When I get the filename of this "4142_062017.TXT" I get "A:.~lock.4142_062017.TXT#". But this file  "0321_062017.TXT" I get "A:\0321_062017.TXT"

Comment: That's what I asked, **how the `fs_infos` list is being populated**. If it is reading directly from some path, check that path, may be possible if that path have any directory with this sort of name.

Comment: Dim fs_infos() As FileInfo = dir_info.GetFiles("*.txt")

Comment: If you populated dir_info like this
**Dim dir_info As New DirectoryInfo("DIRECTORY PATH HERE")**
Your code should be working fine.
If you're still facing the problem you code just replace the **.~lock.** with empty string.

Comment: Means you are getting files from executable path, check that directory, what sort of files are there, post the screen shot of that directory in question here. I doubt there are file names containing these characters.

Comment: ok.I think the problem is on the security of the file or whatever it is. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't both a `A:\.~lock.4142_062017.TXT#` _**and**_ a `A:\4142_062017.TXT` file? It would seem that the former is a hidden copy that some program created either in order to have exclusive access to it or just a backup/cached version of it. Microsoft Word does a similar thing for every document you open.